How to merge or manage builtin data types in Ghidra with GDTs?
I'm trying to understand how Ghidra's GDTs are supposed to be used, particularly the case of builtin data types.
When I create a data type library in Data Type Manager (-> Create File Archive) and import function prototypes to it from a binary with debug information—testing with libm.so.6—that library gets copies of the builtin data types like bool, float, int16 etc. in addition to the ones specific to the binary:
├── BuiltinTypes
│   ├── double
│   ├── float
├── test_library
│   ├── _CAPTURED_FROM_libm.so.6
│   │   ├── __acosf: float __stdcall __acosf(float __x)
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── double
│   ├── float

When I use these libraries to import signatures into programs without full debug symbols, the function definitions often end up containing types like float.conflict. I assume this happens because of the multiple copies of float.
Now, I think I can be fairly sure that all my floats are the same float, which makes me think I would want to make all floats always refer to BuiltinTypes::float.
Here my first attempt was to right click test_library::float, select Replace... and replace it with the float in BuiltinTypes. Unfortunately, doing that changes the __acosf prototype from
float __stdcall __acosf(float __x)
to
undefined __stdcall __acosf(undefined __x)
, which obviously defeats the purpose.
Questions:

Is the intended way of using this to have duplicates of the standard data types in the GDT libraries?
If the answer to (1) is "yes", should I just ignore the .conflict renames? Or get rid of them some other way? How?
If the answer to (1) is "no", how should I get the function prototypes imported so that the types refer to the builtin types?

